# Tables as node labels in ipycytoscape

Tags: python, plotly-dash, cytoscape.js, cytoscape, ipycytoscape

I am using [ipycytoscape](https://github.com/cytoscape/ipycytoscape) in Python to make a version of [Tensorflow's plot_model function for PyTorch](https://machinelearningmastery.com/visualize-deep-learning-neural-network-model-keras/).  I would like to be able to draw, in Cytoscape, a plot like the attached picture.

[image]

If I just try to format strings in the node label with \n end-line characters, Cytoscape removes all the white space characters so I don't get that kind of basic formatting.  I am thinking to use either HTML or format a JPEG image for each label using another plotting package and then insert that image as the node label.

After many hours of Google search I have been unable to find a clear example which formats anything like the above nodes.

Please help me figure out how to make node labels of the above style in either [ipycytoscape](https://github.com/cytoscape/ipycytoscape) or [Dash Plotly Cytoscape](https://dash.plotly.com/cytoscape).

Answer (score 1):

Use SVG background images to render arbitrary content in nodes.  See the SBGN stylesheet [1] for examples, e.g. the open/closed glyphs in the demo [2].  If you make tables with SVG, you may make that an extension similar to the SBGN one.

[1] https://github.com/PathwayCommons/cytoscape-sbgn-stylesheet

[2] https://pathwaycommons.github.io/cytoscape-sbgn-stylesheet/

Comment: Please show how to, in a Jupyter notebook using Python, generate the diagram shown in the SBGN stylesheet demo.  I'm asking because I don't know JS at all, I only know Python, and I'm trying to draw exactly the SBGN kind of diagram, but in Python.